# A new general quartic equation formula

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I discovered this new general quartic equation formula not long ago. If $x^4+px^2+qx+r=0$ then,
$$x_1 = \frac{q}{8k}+\sqrt{-2k - (\frac{q^2}{64k^2}+\frac{p}{2})}$$
$$x_2 = \frac{q}{8k}-\sqrt{-2k - (\frac{q^2}{64k^2}+\frac{p}{2})}$$
$$x_3 = \frac{-q}{8k}+\sqrt{2k - (\frac{q^2}{64k^2}+\frac{p}{2})}$$
$$x_4 = \frac{-q}{8k}-\sqrt{2k - (\frac{q^2}{64k^2}+\frac{p}{2})}$$
Where $k$ is one of the solutions to the equation:
$$4096k^6-256(p^2-4r)k^4-32pq^2k^2-q^4=0$$

If the formula is correct, I want to ask if it is publishable.

Comment: So in order to compute solutions of a fourth order polynomial, we need to solve a sixth order polynomial? When you say *solution*, **which** solution? There are four $x$s but 6 $k$s due to FTA.

Comment: It is a great merit to find by yourself solving methods and formulas but these ones are "avatars" of known ones, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1966497

Comment: @K.defaoite observe that setting $k^2=K$, this reduces to a **3rd degree** polynomial... as I said, in fact, the OP has rediscovered a standard method.

Comment: @Jean Marie Oh, I see now. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: See as well https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2072841